# Is there a way for Artifactory to not store artifacts locally AND propagate response headers from the downstream source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, artifactory

**Background**

We were using Artifactory on our internal network and proxying an S3 bucket as a generic remote repo. The purpose was originally as both a proxy and a cache so that our internal users can access the files from within our network. They don't have access to the open internet.

During development we realized that the S3 objects change from time to time and decided to unset the "Store artifacts locally?" checkbox, since we need Artifactory as a proxy but not necessarily a cache. If S3 goes down we have bigger issues.

This had the unintended consequence of removing the `X-Checksum-*` headers from the HTTP response for (in hindsight) obvious reasons since the S3 objects are being streamed. Alternatively our S3 objects have extra metadata headers that include the checksum ex. `x-amz-meta-digest-sha1`.  We have logic to check for either header to validate the payload.

**The Question**

Can I have Artifactory passthrough the response headers from S3 when we aren't caching the artifacts locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory does not pass-through headers from remote repositories; There is no setting that enables it.

As a workaround, since Artifactory does return the `X-Checksum-Sha1` header if it exists in the response from the remote repository, you can put a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) between Artifactory and S3 which only translates the S3 `x-amz-meta-digest-sha1` header to a `X-Checksum-Sha1` header with the same value.
This should work...

HTH,
Yinon

Comment: I just replaced Artifactory with nginx in this scenario since I only needed a reverse proxy. Thanks for the suggestion.